# C# Удалить повторяющиеся символы из строки

Tags: c#, winforms, строки

Имеется, допустим, 5 текстбоксов. И один главный. По мере заполнения тех пяти текстбоксов, в главном формируется имя. Между значениями текстбоксов используются знаки нижнего подчеркивания `"_"`.

Например:

```
текстбокс1: 123

текстбокс2: 456

текстбокс3: 789

текстбокс4: аа

текстбокс5: бб
```

Главный тексбокс отобразит: `123_456_789_аа_бб`

**В чем проблема:** для создания имени не всегда нужно заполнять все тексбоксы. Иногда достаточно одного или двух.
Тогда мы видим следующее: `123_456___` или `__789__`

Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы в строке при наличии двух подряд и более нижних подчеркиваний оставалось только одно. Исходя из примеров выше вывело бы `123_456` и `789`.

К тому же тут для примера указал,что их 5. В реальности их может быть 10-15.

**Что пробовал:** Методы `Trim()`, `Replace()`, `Remove()` и т.д.
Но решения так и не нашел. Либо удаляет нужные, либо не верно срабатывают.

**UPDATE:**

Для формирования итогового имени использую подобную структуру:

```
string fileName = tb_1.Text + "_" + tb_2.Text + "_" + tb_3.Text + "_" + tb_4.Text + "_" + cb_1.Text + "_" + cb_2.Text + "_" + cb_3.Text + "_" + cb_4.Text + "_" + cb_6.Text + "_" + tb_5.Text + "_" + tb_6.Text + "_" + tb_7.Text;

tb_FullName.Text = fileName;
```

Может есть более простой и правильный способ заполнения,чтобы потом не пришлось удалять нижние подчеркивания?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так.

Берете список

```cs
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
```

Добавляете в него все нужные значения

```cs
lines.Add(textBox1.Text);
lines.Add(textBox2.Text);
//...
```

Дальше у вас 2 варианта:

Либо сразу использовать Linq

```
string result = string.Join("_", lines.Where(s => s?.Length > 0));
```

Либо предварительно императивно в цикле надо удалить пустые строки

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[i]))
    {
        lines.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
string result = string.Join("_", lines);
```

То есть задача эта сводится к тому, чтобы не допустить появления этих дубликатов, а не грамотно их удалить.

---

Однострочник для вашего конкретного случая, с использованием массива вместо списка, но разницы нет.

```cs
tb_FullName.Text = string.Join("_", new string[] { tb_1.Text, tb_2.Text, tb_3.Text, tb_4.Text, cb_1.Text, cb_2.Text, cb_3.Text, cb_4.Text, cb_6.Text, tb_5.Text, tb_6.Text, tb_7.Text }.Where(s => s?.Length > 0));
```

Comment: добавил описание формирования имени в главном текстбоксе. Как в этом случае лучше?

Comment: @MarkKovak что именно не понятно в ответе? по идее он на весь ваш вопрос целиком отвечает.

Comment: не срабатывает почему-то. Может удобнее добавлять нижние подчеркивания, если в строке есть какой-либо символ?
Проверю Ваш способ еще раз и отпишусь.

Comment: @MarkKovak постарайтесь разобраться в коде, который вам предложили. То, что вы хотите сделать, как я понял, - это заменить рядом стоящие повторяющиеся символы `_` на один символ `_`. Не идите этим путем, стройте имя сразу правильно. А то вы сначала строите неправильное имя, а потом уже его пытаетесь "пофиксить".

Comment: @aepot решение в одну строку работает идеально! спасибо огромное! пометил Ваш ответ как решение!